# How to delete the string pattern from a file between 2 colon character

Tags: sed

Searched a lot lot but didn't find any solution.

for example: if  string is

```
a12345:hello world:hello world again:other string
```

output:

```
a12345::hello world again:other string
```

so I just wanted to delete the content between 1st and 2nd colon character

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed`:

```
sed 's/:[^:]*/:/'
```

- first `:` - match colon
- `[^:]*` - match any number of characters which are not a colon
- last `:` - replace the match with colon, because your match includes the first colon, but from your output I see you want to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/:[^:]*/:/' file_name
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F':' -v OFS=":" '{$2="";print}' file_name
```

Comment: your `sed` is exactly what I answered before with an added `g` which makes it wrong.

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1227561/431864